# Certificate revocation list in LDAP

Tags: ldap, ldif, opendj, certificate-revocation

I need to store a Certificate Revocation List in LDAP server (OpenDJ). I have used ldapmodify command to store a certificate in the LDAP server by adding entries to LDIF files. However, I am not really sure how to go about adding a revocation list in the LDAP server.

Any examples using LDIF would be really appreciated.

Comment: Well you're going to add it to either a new entry or an existing entry of type `certificationAuthority`, `cRLDistributionPoint`, or `pkiCA`, and you're going to add it to a `certificateRevocationList` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As EJP pointed out, there is a standard schema for CRL.
Just one thing, LDAP doesn't have a specific syntax for CRLs or Certificates.
The CRL needs to be treated as an opaque blob and you will need to use the ;binary transfer option when creating, updating or retrieving the attribute.
In LDIF, it's as simple as:
certificateRevocationList;binary:: BASE64_Encoding of CRL

Comment: I should add that OpenDJ delivers the schema for CRLs by default.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense!